# Realtime visualization dashboard for questions and answers on a geographical map

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

It would be cool to have a real-time visualization similar to [IPViking Live](http://map.ipviking.com/)<sup>1</sup> with questions being asked and questions being answered/accepted geographically.

Plus in the profile tab there could be a daily timeline tab which shows attacks (on questions, rather say help) made by you geographically with a draggable cursor over time for that day.

---

<sup>1: You may have to use Chrome to see that url in action.</sup>

Comment: +1 That would look amazingly cool, but I don't see any real application for idea though and even if the post hits over 100 I still can't see SE implementing it.

Comment: woudldn't it show how awesome community is in real time with real data ? not very useful for developers but definately useful for them to showcase

Comment: Well that's about the only reason, to "show off" the community. Don't  get me wrong I like the idea I'm just giving a practical view of the proposal.

Comment: The dangerous part of this is that *I would sit and watch it for hours*...I'm still upvoting though, I laugh in the face of danger!

Comment: We should keep the "Attack origins" part, it makes sense for most questions...

Comment: Do SE save the IP adresses of the users?

Comment: Who doesn't these days

Comment: Even if SE doesn't I am sure their WAF has logs.

Comment: By the way, [this already exists for github](https://github.com/arscan/encom-boardroom) (see second screenshot).  We can probably create one ourselves in the same way [using the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs)...  "Sniff" the locations based on users' profiles, possibly, if it's accessible through that (or if not, just parse the profile page)

Comment: No, SO should not spend developer time and server resources on a feature that is absolutely useless for the core functionality of the site. I'd rather they spend their time and resources to improve the Q/A process, fine-tune the question-ban algorithm, or implement any of the actually useful feature request.

Comment: @izkata link to the globe as standalone library : https://github.com/arscan/encom-globe there is also this : https://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe